# How to inject angular 1.5 components dynamically, based on a condition?

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

here is a small fragment of my code:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-default text-center">{{p.Name}}</div>
    <div class="list-group-item">
        <!--Using bootstrap form-group for each field -->
        <div ng-repeat="f in p.Fields">

            <!--Here I want to inject components dynamically-->
            <!--<text-field></text-field>-->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in  `<div ng-repeat="f in p.Fields">...</div>` I need to inject corresponding component, such as `<text-field>`, `<text-area-field>` etc... **dynamically**, based on a condition:

if (f.type == "TEXTFIELD") >>> inject `<text-field>`component
if (f.type == "TEXTAREAFIELD") >>> inject `<text-area-field>`component

and so on...

Whats the best way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it on this way:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-default text-center">{{p.Name}}</div>
    <div class="list-group-item">
        <!--Using bootstrap form-group for each field -->
        <div ng-repeat="f in p.Fields">

            <div ng-if="f.type == 'TEXTFIELD'">
               <text-field></text-field>
            </div>

            <div ng-if="f.type == 'TEXTAREAFIELD'">
               <text-area-field></text-area-field>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no point in wrapping the component inside a `div`. You can place `ngIf` on it.

Comment: "You can place ngIf on it" - tried, doesnt work, only if I wrap it with div with ngIf

Answer (score 2):

It depends if the input you are printing to the page needs to be used by angular also (ng-model).

If so, you need the **$compile** provider.

I suggest making a directive to handle this. You could have :

```
 <div ng-repeat="f in p.Fields">
      <x-your-directive params={{f}}>
 </div>
```

In your directive, you would recieve the data to parse via `attrs.params`

You then need to inject yourself the **$compile**, the same way as you would for **$scope, services, etc.**

You could then apply the new input with angular.element (which is jQLite).

To do so, and for angular to understand the newly created DOM element, that's where you use **$compile**.

**$compile** will tell angular to re-parse the element dynamically.

Example:

```
angular.module('your_module', []).directive('yourDirective', ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controllerAs: 'YourCtrl',
        controller: [function() {}],
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            // Switch case on attrs.params (which is f in p.Fields)
            if (attrs.params === 'TEXTFIELD') {
                element.html($compile('<input type="text"/>')($scope))
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

The cool thing about this, is that it works for directives also (the printing part). Therefor, if you want to dynamically add Directives to your DOM, you can :)

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting, but I need the templates to be separate cshtml files, not strings (dev requirements)

Comment: Have you tried using the ng-include ? IF that doesnt work, wrap your templates into separate directives, then call the directive name (which will load the template) But make sure ng-include works for your needs (less hassle)

Comment: The solution Igor Janković showed seems like a good and simple way to accomplish what I need

Comment: Yes, but is not a good practice. Give it a few months time and the file will become messy pretty quickly. If this is a personal project its fine, but his answer is not production clean code.

Comment: Its ok, we need other people to be able to edit these html templates on regular basis, *without* needing to know typescript (they dont know TS) and without needing to compile typescript components, I write these components in typescript.